# How to Pause an Application without Freezing the UI

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, progress-bar

On my click event I want to show an indeterminate progressbar for a certain amount of time, and then resume the application. The problem I am having is that I cannot get the progressbar to show. Could someone help with this?

```
private void RunTestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (testRunning == false)
            {
                testRunning = true;

                //Set progress bar visibility
                PerformanceProgressbar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                PerformanceProgressbar.IsIndeterminate = true;

                //Tell the app to pause for 5 seconds so the user sees the progress bar


                //Set progress bar visibility
                PerformanceProgressbar.IsIndeterminate = false;
                PerformanceProgressbar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

                testRunning = false;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [Task.Delay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .. and `await` the result:

```
await Task.Delay(5000);
```

You will need to make sure you mark your event as `async` too:

```
private async void RunTestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: Thanks. After some research, and I am in fact using async methods in another part of my app, this definitely seems promising. I will have to test it later, but my main question is, this will allow the rest of the processes in a method to run and update the screen while also pausing the completion of the method for 5 seconds? Im still a bit fuzzy on the intricacies.

Comment: Correct.. it will. The internals of async/await are very interesting. The short version is yes, this will block the current method but continue to run other code.. including code in the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

PerformanceProgressbar is control, so you should put it on your page (use fade also).

But if you need to do some task on UI thread (do you really need it?) I recommend you to fade your page by showing semitransparent border over it, and show [ProgressIndicator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.progressindicator%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) in statusbar. It's system object and will run even if app is frozen.

Comment: I do like your ideas. I'm assuming by status bar you mean the system tray. The only thing about that is when it runs the entire system tray is displayed, with time and everything correct?

Comment: @Matthew Yes system tray with time. You can show message there and progressindicator, so it will run even if app totally frozen

Comment: I would like to try this out, but I have the need to show text without the progress bar and with the progress bar active. I've seen a reference to this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560301/how-to-sync-the-titlebar-with-systemtray-on-windows-phone-8 but might you offer a better solution? Haven't tested to see if this works with setting `IsVisible = true` to show the Text but not the scrolling dots along the top.

Comment: @Matthew I have no better solution. You cat set IsIndeterminate = false, Value = 0 and Show title without progressbar.